# JDBC connection url issue

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

i am getting error on below url connection as "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens"
My url

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class JdbcSQLServerConnection {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String url="jdbc:sqlserver://"TKSQA";databaseName="RDK";integratedSecurity=true";


    String query="use RDK 
    go
    /* * the current date must be less than 45 days after the policy effective date and the transaction must have
           * a status of IssuedRenewal */
    select top 5 left(prsnAddr.PostalZip, 5) as ZipCode, policy.policynum,terms.termeffective
    from PolicyRecord pr left join Policy policy on pr.PolicySK = policy.PolicySK
    join PolicyTerms terms on pr.PolicyTermSK = terms.PolicyTermSK and getDate() < (terms.termeffective + 45)
    join PolicyTxn txn on pr.PolicyTxnSK = txn.PolicyTxnSK and TxnBusStatus = 'ISSUEDRENEWAL'  and txn.TxnSequence = (
           select max(ptx2.TxnSequence) 
           from PolicyTxn ptx2 
           inner join PolicyTermTxn pttx2 on pttx2.PolicyTxnsk = ptx2.PolicyTxnSK
           where pttx2.PolicyTermSK = terms.PolicyTermSK and ptx2.TxnStatus <> 'INACTIVE') 
    join Insured ins on ins.PolicyRecordSK= pr.PolicyRecordSK
    join Person pers on pers.PersonSK = ins.PersonSK
    join PersonAddress prsnAddr on prsnAddr.PersonSK = pers.PersonSK
           where policy.insuranceproductid like '%CollectorVehicle%' and RecordType='ONSET' 
           order by terms.TermEffective
    ";


    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

    rs.next();
    String zip= rs.getString("ZipCode");
    System.out.print(zip);
    st.close();
    con.close();


        }

    }
```

Due to the above error i am unable to connect sql sever using java.Is this the correct way to write string url

Comment: mysql and sqlserver are different.

Comment: "*I am unable to connect mysql sever*" - of course you are. That URL is for **SQL Server** not for MySQL. The correct URL format is documented in the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/

Comment: kindly read the question again before downvoting

Comment: Why have you tagged your question with _mysql_ if your question is about SQL Server. And the code as shown will not even compile. Please post the full code and the exception stacktrace (and **edit** your question, don't use comments).

Comment: please check again

Comment: That code will not compile, you can't have `String url="jdbc:sqlserver://"TKSQA";databaseName="RDK";integratedSecurity=true";` like that.

Comment: besides the url is it the correct way to pass long query in code. unable to pass long code in query

Answer (score -1):

The general form of the connection URL is (for MS SQL Server)

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]
```

example,

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;user=MyUserName;password=*****;
```

The general form of the connection URL is (for MySQL Server)

```
jdbc:mysql://hostname/ databaseName
```

Here, hostname should contain portnumber (its mandatory)

example,

```
  //STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class JDBCExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/STUDENTS";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

      //STEP 4: Execute a query

   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
    conn.close();
   }//end finally
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}
}
```

**References,**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm

Comment: MySQL port number is not mandatory, and it's irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Okay, I have never tried 
w/o port number, thank you.
I will try it.